# How to read structure from a pipe in C (Windows)

Tags: c, windows, process, operating-system, pipe

I changed the standart input of child process to reading handle of the pipe.I created pipe with both ends in parent.c file and updated child's standart input with pipe's reading handle like that si.hStdInput = hReadPipe;

I am trying to write this structure to the pipe:

```
struct textShift{
   char* text;
   int shift;
};
```

Here is how parent process writes to the pipe:

```
while(1)
{
    printf("Please enter your message:");
    gets(ts.text);
    printf("Please enter shift number:");
    scanf("%d",&ts.shift);
    bytesToWrite = strlen(ts.text)+1; 
    WriteFile(hWritePipe[0], &ts, bytesToWrite, &bytesWritten,NULL); 
    printf("number of bytes: %d\n number of bytes successfully sent: %d",bytesToWrite, bytesWritten);
    printf("%s", ts.text);
}
```

However I don't know how to read this structure in my child process. For string, I use getchar in my child process file:

```
int main()

{
char message[100];
int i;
while(1)
{
    for(i=0; (message[i]=getchar())!=0; i++){}

    printf("message from parent: %s", message);

}

system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

How can I get this structure from pipe in child process?

Comment: You need to open the other end of the pipe and read it with ReadFile. Your code is asking for buffer overruns, BTW

Comment: I created pipe with both ends in parent.c file and updated child's standart input with pipe's reading handle like that si.hStdInput = hReadPipe; .To reach the handle of reading pipe, should I make it global in parent?

Comment: Sorry, I updated the question.

Comment: You need to show exactly how you transferred the read end of the pipe to the child. It needs to be secured and the handle made inheritable. Show all the code that we need to reproduce. Read about SSCCE.

Comment: If you _really_ want to write/read the structure, the data transferred would be a _pointer_ and an `int`.  Quite simple.  But it appears you want something else: a C string pointed by the first field `text` and then an `int` of the 2nd field.